# Restricting edits for specific fields in a feature class for particular users

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, editing

How to restrict edits for specific fields in a feature class for particular users in ArcSDE.

For example, there is a feature class called “Tower”. It has 20 Fields. Out of 20 fields, 10 are updated by interface.
So these “10” attributes should not be editable by “Editor” group of desktop GIS users. They may edit the other attributes in this feature class.

Comment: Geodatabases do not support the concept of column-based permissions. Please **edit** the question to specify the RDBMS in use, the exact RDBMS version, the version of ArcGIS in use, the geodatabase version (if different), and details of what you have tried to find a solution (e.g. placing attributes in a related table, unchecking the uneditable attributes from the layer defimition,...)

Comment: Is it possible in Arc Map.

Comment: I don't think so, but I've never tried.  This likely won't have a trivial solution, so demonstrating that you've put some effort into the problem may be necessary to avoid getting this closed as *too broad* or *unclear*.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 approaches using ArcObjects or ArcPy.

1. Use a [class extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IObjectClassEvents.htm) to  to check edits made in an edit session against the values in the parent version and reset the value or cancel the edit if a difference is found.
2. You can also use a custom form to replace the [editor window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IObjectInspector.htm) in ArcMap. This method isn't foolproof since editors can still edit the table directly.
3. Finally you can use an [editor extension](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#3e306e15-d0f9-4c0c-a6b7-ef9c69077132.htm) addin. This is similar to the first option but is application specific, it will only work if the editor has the addin added to their ArcMap application. It listens to edit events instead of database events as the first option does.

The second option can also be combined with either the first or the second. All involve quite a bit of programming, either in ArcObjects or in ArcPy depending on your approach.